# How to get the string from html file?

Tags: asp.net

How should I search for and get a string from html files using **c#** in **asp.net**? This is the code:

```
 private string getHtml(string key)
 {
     StreamReader f = new StreamReader("path");
     string htmlTag = key;
     string str = f.ReadToEnd().ToString();
     Match m = Regex.Match(str, "<" + htmlTag + ">" + "(.*)" + "</" +   
                                htmlTag + ">", RegexOptions.Singleline);
     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);             
     return str;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your RegEx, try changing this:

```
"(.*)"
```

to this:

```
"([^<]*)"
```

So, instead of matching ANY character, you match any characters up to (but not including) the next less-than symbol.

You might also want to change this:

```
"</" + htmlTag + ">"
```

to this

```
"</ ?" + htmlTag + ">"
```

To allow for a space after the slash (you can ignore this second suggestion if you have full control over the HTML documents and know exactly how they were coded)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Html Agility Pack, available here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just noting here (as required per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156184) that the library Simon is recommending is one that he is the author of.