# HTML find and replace href tags

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

I am parsing an HTML file. I need find all the href tags in an html and replace them
with a text friendly version.

Here is an example.

```
Original Text: <a href="http://foo.bar">click here</a> 
replacement value: click here <http://foo.bar>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Cue the regex flame war.

Comment: with a regexp and backreferences

Comment: @Cyborgx37 he is not asking for `regex`..question is **valid**

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It - I know. But such an open ended question is sure to result in an answer containing regex, followed by the obligatory [You can't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), followed by [Oh yes you can!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 It would result in **Oh yes you can!** when you get plain textual data out of the html tags...

Comment: In any case... answer is easy enough to find on stackoverflow or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?oq=parse+html+c%23&q=parse+html+c%23). I don't see any [research effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Html Agility Pack library](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), with a code like this:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(myHtmlFile); // load your file

        // select recursively all A elements declaring an HREF attribute.
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode(node.InnerText + " <" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null) + ">"), node);
        }

        doc.Save(Console.Out); // output the new doc.
```

Comment: Just noting here (as required per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156184) that the library Simon is recommending is one that he is the author of. It's most notable current competitor is [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).